# Application force closes with error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableRow

Tags: android, sqlite

this is the TeacherLoginPage.java which oncreate sets the layout by fething data from the database.Here in the the onCreate method i had assigned id of the check boxes with setid() method.
the problem here is when i click the update button the application force closes.
I think the line `cbArray.add((CheckBox) findViewById(resId));`is not working.
should i write as (R.id.resId)?

**TeacherLoginPage.java**

```
    LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_checklist);

    for (int i = 0; i < Array_Count; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setId(i);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);

        checkBox.setId(i);
        checkBox.setText(Roll_array.get(i));
        row.addView(checkBox);
        my_layout.addView(row);
    }  

 public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<CheckBox> cbArray = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
        int[] cvalue = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < Array_Count; j++) {
            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(j), "id", getPackageName());
            cbArray.add((CheckBox) findViewById(resId));
            cvalue[j] = toNumericalValue(cbArray.get(j).isChecked());
        }
        insertAttendanceDatabase(TeacherLoggedInPage.this, cvalue);

    }

    private void insertAttendanceDatabase(
            TeacherLoggedInPage teacherLoggedInPage, int[] cvalue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getWritableDatabase();

        int length = cvalue.length;

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("teacher_id", t_id);
        cv.put("time", DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
        for (int i = 0; i < cvalue.length; i++) {

            cv.put(Roll_array.get(i), cvalue[i]);
        }

        try {
            db.insert(DbHelper.ATTENDANCE_TABLE, null, cv);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private int toNumericalValue(boolean checked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (checked)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Here's the **LogCat**

```
08-12 04:17:14.970: D/AndroidRuntime(385): Shutting down VM
08-12 04:17:14.999: W/dalvikvm(385): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableRow
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.example.attendancesystem.TeacherLoggedInPage.onClick(TeacherLoggedInPage.java:123)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-12 04:17:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 04:17:38.108: I/Process(385): Sending signal. PID: 385 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Thanks for all your feedbacks!
i made the changes but now it shows another error at line 125 i.e
null pointer Exception at line:
cvalue[j] = toNumericalValue(cbArray.get(j).isChecked());

Comment: can anybody tell me how to resolve this problem??

Comment: You have not initialize your array  int[] cvalue = null;

Comment: yes i have initialized it globally but result is the same ...:(

Comment: debug if cvalue is null or cbArray.get(j) is null. Chances are cvalue could be null as it is clearly visible in above code.   Try as below      int[] cvalue = new int[Array_Count];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you set your ID twice:

```
row.setId(i);
```

and later

```
checkBox.setId(i);
```

What is happening then if you do `findViewById(resId)` is that it returns the first element it finds with this ID, which is a `TableRow`, and not a `CheckBox` as you expected. Hence the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedbacks! i made the changes but now it shows another error at line 125 i.e null pointer Exception at line: cvalue[j] = toNumericalValue(cbArray.get(j).isChecked());

Comment: Either `cbArray.get(j)` is null, or your `cvalue[]` array is still null. Did you forget to initialize it? (only a guess)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast a `TableRow` to a `CheckBox`. Make sure that the id is pointing to a `CheckBox`

Comment: Thanks for all your feedbacks! i made the changes but now it shows another error at line 125 i.e null pointer Exception at line: cvalue[j] = toNumericalValue(cbArray.get(j).isChecked());

Answer (score 0):

Here is the point, you assign the id for `TableRow` earlier but then when you retrieve from the resId, you cast into `CheckBox` which cause the problem. Check this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array_Count; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setId(i);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and this:

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> cbArray = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
        int[] cvalue = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < Array_Count; j++) {
            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(j), "id", getPackageName());
            cbArray.add((CheckBox) findViewById(resId));
            cvalue[j] = toNumericalValue(cbArray.get(j).isChecked());
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning same id to TableRow and Checkbox. as

```
 row.setId(i);

 checkBox.setId(i);
```

Just comment `//row.setId(i);`

Comment: Thanks for all your feedbacks! i made the changes but now it shows another error at line 125 i.e null pointer Exception at line: cvalue[j] = toNumericalValue(cbArray.get(j).isChecked());